# How to make an array contain only numbers with anonymous object export?

Tags: typescript

I have this `record` which only accepts `number[]` or `numbers`.

It looks like this:

```js
type numberRecords = Record<string,number[]|number>;
```

I know it works because this errors out:

```js
export const myList:numberRecords = {
    a: ["a",2]
}
```

But this doesn't:

```js
export default <numberRecords> {
    a: ["a",2]
}
```

Why does this happen? Should I go with a named object or anonymous, default object? I'd prefer the later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<numberRecord>`, you're telling TypeScript: "I know what I'm doing, ignore any type warnings that might otherwise arise and assume that the object is of type `numberRecords`.

This is the same as doing

```
export default {
    a: ["a",2]
} as numberRecords;
```

Both of these approaches are dangerous - only use `as` or `<someType>` to assert a type when you have no other option, otherwise your code's typings may well not be safe, as you're seeing here.

In contrast, using

```
const someVariableName: someType = ...
```

indicates to the compiler that `someVariableName` *should satisify* `someType` (and if it doesn't, TS will throw an error). This approach is much safer.

If you want to do this, I'd recommend declaring the variable and its type beforehand, then exporting it as default:

```
const myList: numberRecords = {
    a: ["a",2]
};
export default myList;
```